# Inverse pair in Pine script

Tags: pine-script, inverse

I am aware of the alt+I inverse scale function in Tradingview. How do I apply an inverse function within a Pine script, instead of loading e.g. an inverse pair as done in the MWE below?

```
//@version=4
study(title="", overlay=false)

timeperiod = "1"

v1 = security("FX_IDC:CADAUD", timeframe.period, close)

lengthFast = input(3,  minval = 0, title = "Fast MA on RSI")
rFast = rsi(v1, lengthFast)
fastMA1  = sma(rFast, lengthFast) 

plot(fastMA, "Fast MA", color=color.red, linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually need to call the symbol itself it can be done like this, however there isn't a way to validate if the symbol is an actual valid symbol or not.

```
//@version=4
study("Inverse Ticker", overlay = true)

var string ticker = syminfo.prefix + ":" + syminfo.currency + syminfo.basecurrency

inv_close = security(ticker, timeframe.period, close)

plot(inv_close)
```

Otherwise you can just use `1 / close`

eg for AUDCAD where ***y*** equals the current close price

1 x AUD = ***y*** x CAD

(1 x AUD) / ***y*** = (***y*** x CAD) / ***y***

(1 x AUD) / ***y*** = 1 x CAD

= 1 / ***y***

For inverted candles :

```
//@version=4
study("Inverse", overlay = false)

o = 1 / open
h = 1 / high
l = 1 / low
c = 1 / close

plotcandle(open = o, high = h, low = l, close = c, title = "Inverse pair", color = c >= o ? color.green : color.red, wickcolor = color.gray)
```

Comment: You could do the calculations for ohlc and use plotcandle() instead of plot(). You need to do it for each 1 / open, 1 / high etc.

Comment: The script for inverted candles return candles with are mirrored (which they should be), but mirrored so that mininum values for the non-inverted values align with maximum values for the inverted values. I believe that is not correct inverse values? https://www.tradingview.com/chart/ZARAUD/O9SpG0aD-InverseV2/

Comment: the issue with inverted values and mentioned in my previous comment is about pinning values correctly to the axis in the plot. For the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70368687/ema-not-plotting-correctly-or-human-error/70370099#70370099

Comment: When plotting it, I need to make the original non-inverted chart nonvisible. I do that by clicking the eye right in the upper left corner of the chart. But the scaling is not correct. Not even if I "Pin To Scale". Any ideas to this? https://www.tradingview.com/chart/USDJPY/wHPN0ROE-no-scale/

Comment: Also, the inverted function does not relate to the other indicators on the chart. It has an offset compared to the other indicators

Comment: Have you tried assigning the original to no scale and the inverted to the right scale? You'll also have to use the inverted as the source input for other indicators to have them correspond

Comment: Assigning 'no scale' to the original plot yields: https://www.tradingview.com/chart/USDJPY/wXqu3uZx-mirror Making the original plot nonvisible reveals an issue with scaling of the new plot - notice all values are equal to 0.009 https://www.tradingview.com/chart/USDJPY/KPdLpWsI-scaling/

Comment: Could you please tell me how to use the inverted data as the source input? https://www.tradingview.com/chart/USDJPY/xADFiZfB-source/ (assigning it to the same  scale as the inverted source seems not to be the solution)

Comment: to fix the scale you need to pin the inverse script to a new scale and set `precision = 5`  inside `study()`. If you add this line to your inverse script you will be able to select is as the source for other indicators. `plot(c, color = #00000000, title = "Inverse close")`

Comment: The inverted scale works properly, with your latest comments, thank you. If I apply, say, a moving average, then it follows the original plot: https://www.tradingview.com/chart/EURUSD/hloqaoge-scale/ Assigning the scale of the inverted plot makes it "explode": https://www.tradingview.com/chart/EURUSD/VHzNvDFf-scale-a/

Comment: You have to change the source for the ema in the ema's settings to the inverted plotted output (the above plot(c) line you had to add). You also need to check the ema is assigned to the same scale as the inverted candles.

Comment: So the MA needs the c = 1 / close and src = input(c, title="Source") ?  
//@version=5
indicator(title="MAv1", shorttitle="MAv1", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
c = 1/close
len = input.int(3, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(c, title="Source")
offset = input.int(title="Offset", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out = ta.sma(src, len)
plot(out, color=color.blue, title="MA", offset=offset) ? Syntax error: Arguments of input function must be of constant type, or 'source' builtin variables.

Comment: Yes, I have already checked that the MA is assigned to the new scaling

Comment: Well, you could include the code for doing the ema yourself in your inverse script using `c`. Otherwise if you're using the standard ema indicator separately you have to change the ema indicator's SETTINGS (the cog icon next to the script name top left) for the source to use the inverse script's plot of `c`.

Comment: OK, now I see what you mean, and it is working. Great! THANK YOU!