# ema not plotting correctly! (or human error?)

Tags: pine-script

Orange bar shown on the plots do not correspond to the expected places?

https://www.tradingview.com/chart/ZARAUD/03uXsufA-orange-bar/

```
//@version=5
indicator("TestEma10")

ema10 = ta.ema(close, 10)

test = ta.crossover(ema10, close)

plot(ema10)    

bgcolor(test? color.orange:na)
```

Copy-paste the code into a Pine script, and draw the plot lines with the mouse into the main chart to get the linked chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pinned your indicator to the left scale, while the price is pinned to the right scale.
That way they won't lign up.

What you did to pin the indicator to the left scale was:
Right-click ema10 line > Pin To Scale (Now Right) > Pine To New Left Scale

[image: Pin to left]

What you need to do to restore the indicator to the right scale is:
Right-click ema10 line > Pin To Scale (Now Z) > Pine To Scale A

[image: Pin restore]

Comment: Is it possible to pin it using pine script, i.e. without the graphical user interface?